# ASP.NET WebService returning List<> using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

This is my WebService Method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

public string getlastimages()
{
    DBservices DBS = new DBservices();
    List<string> ImageUrls = new List<string>();
    try
    {
       DBS.getLastImages();
       ImageUrls = DBS.ImgUrlList;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonImage = js.Serialize(ImageUrls);
    return jsonImage;
}
```

This is the data that i'm receiving after running this method:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
["~\\images\\benny\\1149468-18.jpg","~\\images\\lior\\photo4.jpg","~\\images\\oren\\photo3.jpg","~\\images\\oren\\photo2.jpg","~\\images\\oren\\photo1.jpg"]
</string>
```

I'm new with $.ajax method, and I need help writing the $.ajax method to retrieve this data from that list.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no need to convert the `List<string>` to json formatted string. It will be handled internally by using `JavaScriptSerializer`, since you already decorated with `[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]`. [Check MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.responseformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script
[ScriptService]
public class Service: System.Web.Services.WebService 
{
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]    
    public List<string> getlastimages()
    {
      DBservices DBS = new DBservices();
      List<string> ImageUrls = new List<string>();
      try
      {
       DBS.getLastImages();
       ImageUrls = DBS.ImgUrlList;
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
        throw ex;
      }
      return ImageUrls;
    }
}
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({

url:"service.asmx/getlastimages",
type:"POST",
dataType:'json',
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success:function(data){
   var result;
   if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
    result=data.d;// ASP.Net framework will add d
   }
   else
   {
    result=data;
   }
}
});
```